# What is the difference between "wireless" and "wifi"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [wireless](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) and [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi). Is is appropriate to merge and make the two synonyms?

The majority of the questions in both tags are dealing with wireless networking.

If it is not appropriate to merge them, what is the difference between the two? The wiki descriptions of the two are not clear on the differences.

[wireless](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless):

> For questions concerning the existing or potential wireless functionality of a computing device. Use the [remote-control] tag if the device is not directly related to computers.

[wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi):

> Use this tag when searching for devices for wireless network access. This can include devices such as routers, wireless extenders, wireless access points and more.

Answer (score 4):

There *are* differences between the two tags.

- [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) is just that, WiFi.
- [wireless](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) could encompass other radios or frequency bands, including Bluetooth, radio signals, and wireless communications from mobile phones.

That doesn't *necessarily* mean they shouldn't be merged, though. "Wireless" is often used interchangeably with WiFi, so it may be appropriate to synonmyize them, though perhaps not to merge them without sorting the existing questions to filter out any Bluetooth, radio, etc questions.

Comment: I could get on board with a synonym creation since the two are relatively close. It would require some work though like you said.

Comment: +1, synonymize, but don't merge. It's either that or merge them and replace the old "wireless" with "radio" because that is another term for what is meant by that word in the broader sense.

Comment: Don't merge. Re-tag the ones using [tag:wireless] while talking about [tag:wifi]. Or dual-tag. But merging gets complicated when talking about more general radios like Bluetooth and all it's related friends that don't necessarily have their own tag.

Answer (score 2):

[wireless](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) can cover WiFi, wireless keyboards, wireless mice, wireless headphones, and a wide range of other wireless devices, without really specifying how they communicate beyond "not wires".

[bluetooth](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) refers exclusively to wireless devices that use the Bluetooth protocol to communicate.

[wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) refers exclusively to devices that communicate using the IEEE 802.11 family of standards.

The hypothetical [infrared](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrared) would be used for someone looking for a wireless device that communicates using IrDA, CIR, or a similar optical standard.

[wireless](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) isn't a good tag, but it isn't an obvious synonym for [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi), either.